# Hosted checkout page - who holds liability if there is fraud case?

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

We are planning to use the hosted checkout page - does it minimize our liability and security measures? In the event of hacking of our website or poor security of the website, does it affect the customer's credit card information?

If there is a fraud case, is it our liability or hosted payment gateways liability? I read that you need lot of security to use the non-hosted payment gateway.

Comment: Could you clarify what hosted checkout page you're talking about? What payment gateway? Third-party extension, or built-in?

Comment: actually it is our native bank's payment gateway, and once the user is goin for the payment, it redirects to their payment page and redirects back

Comment: is this for a magento store?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the gateways responsibility to make sure that they are PCI-DSS compliant and secure from intrusion so in large part they may be responsible but as with most cc processors you may have a difficult time getting them to accept responsibility. You may also be partially liable because you are the party that referred them to a potentially insecure site. It's really difficult to say for sure but let's hope you never need to find out.

Just be certain that you don't ever store customer payment data on your own server.